# ORACLE SQL QUERY SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with my query

```
select distinct count(item_number), creation_date
from EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B ,
```

all I need to count the item number every month
for example

```
3-9-2020      count:29700
4-9-2020      count:29600
5-9-2020      Count:30000
```

and get the all date for the month and the previous month from creation_id or sysdate any of them

thanks

Comment: It is a little unclear on what the first column as to do with the month, especially because the count should be in the first column according to the query.

Comment: Does your question have **anything at all** to do with `SYSDATE`? If it does, you didn't explain it very well; you may want to try again. And if it doesn't, why do you have `SYSDATE` in the title of your question?

Comment: "a _little_ unclear" is being charitable.  Please read and heed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

To count the number per month, you would aggregate by the month:

```
select trunc(creation_date, 'MON') as yyyymm, count(*)
from EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
group by trunc(creation_date, 'MON');
```

Comment: how to get the data every month based on the current day where I run the query, and how to calculate the previous data with the new one until , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear; perhaps you're trying to get

```
select TRUNC(CREATION_DATE), count(item_number)
  from EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
  WHERE TRUNC(CREATION_DATE)
          IN (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1),
              TRUNC(SYSDATE),
              ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 1))
  GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATION_DATE)
```

### EDIT

Apparently OP wants a running monthly count, so something like:

```
WITH cteLimits (START_DATE, END_DATE)
       AS (SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -2), ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1) - INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
           SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1), TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
           SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE), ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 1) - INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM DUAL),
     cteDay_totals
       AS (SELECT TRUNC(CREATION_DATE) AS CREATION_DATE,
                  COUNT(*) AS DAY_TOTAL
             FROM EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
             GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATION_DATE))
SELECT l.START_DATE,
       l.END_DATE,
       SUM(d.DAY_TOTAL) AS MONTH_TOTAL
  FROM cteLimits l
  INNER JOIN cteDay_totals d
    ON d.CREATION_DATE BETWEEN l.START_DATE AND l.END_DATE
  GROUP BY l.START_DATE,
           l.END_DATE
```

Comment: I mean if the count in 4-9 is 4000 then from 4-9 to 5-9 I created 400 so the count of 5-9 be 4400, not 400, thanks anyway and it will be calculated every month from the current day